# Regular Expression match CREATE TABLE - timeout issue

Tags: regex, t-sql, notepad++

I'm having trouble with a regular expression I've developed specifically for dealing with migration from SQL Server 2012 to 2008.  If you've done this process before, you know that you can't use SSIS to copy Timestamp columns or you will get an error message.  To work around this, I developed a regex to comment out all the timestamp columns for the destination database, then SSIS works fine.

Now I'm trying to develop a regex to collect all the timestamp columns into a single script so that I can add all those missing columns I left out before (there are over 200).  Here is a sample code from the file:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PNotice]    Script Date: 7/27/2015 10:30:32 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PNotice](
    [NoticeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NoticeText] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
--  [TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PNotice_NoticeID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [NoticeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UpdateType]    Script Date: 7/27/2015 10:30:32 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UpdateType](
    [ItemType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemDescripton] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

This sample file shows two tables, one with a timestamp column and one without.  So I wrote a regex to match the entire CREATE TABLE clause, only for tables with a commented timestamp column.  The regex appears to work fine for a little while, then at a certain point in the master script it suddenly matches the entire file, as though it timed out or reached some internal limit:

Expanded:

```
^CREATE TABLE ([^(]+)\(
(?:
  [^-()]|\n|
  (?:
    \(
    (?:
      [^()]|\n
    )+
    \)
  )
)+
--\s+\[([^\]]+)\] \[timestamp\]
(?:
  [^-()]|\n|
  (?:
    \(
    (?:
      [^()]|\n
    )+
    \)
  )
)+
\) ON \[PRIMARY\](?: TEXTIMAGE_ON \[PRIMARY\])?$
```

Single expression:

```
^CREATE TABLE ([^(]+)\((?:[^-()]|\n|(?:\((?:[^()]|\n)+\)))+--\s+\[([^\]]+)\] \[timestamp\](?:[^-()]|\n|(?:\((?:[^()]|\n)+\)))+\) ON \[PRIMARY\](?: TEXTIMAGE_ON \[PRIMARY\])?$
```

The idea is to find CREATE TABLE, then table name, then all of the contents until we find the final closing parenthesis.  It is complicated by the fact there are often parenthesized sub-expressions inside the CREATE TABLE clause, so I added handling for those.  Finally, I want to make sure the timestamp column is present, so I duplicated my entire match expression for matching stuff before and after the timestamp column.

Here is an online example demonstrating it working: http://regexr.com/3bfns.  This final version works great... until at some point in the file it just blows up with no explanation.  Here is an alternative SQL sample that will demonstrate the problem: http://pastebin.com/JtGh6tfM. (WARNING: If you try and paste this in regexr tester, it may lock up your browser.  Try it in Notepad++ to see the issue I was talking about, where it runs for about 10 seconds, then just highlights the whole file).

I'm not sure if my regex is too complicated, or if there is some timeout built-in to NotePad++ regex matcher, or if there is some bug in my regex?  How can I make it more efficient so it can handle a very large file without issues like this?

Comment: Here is a bit more optimized regex: [`^CREATE TABLE ([^(]+)\((?:[^-()]|(?:\([^()]+\)))+--\s+\[([^]]+)] \[timestamp](?:[^-()]|(?:\([^()]+\)))+\) ON \[PRIMARY](?: TEXTIMAGE_ON \[PRIMARY])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/kS4qZ2/1), but I did not try to change anything in it.

Comment: Why don't you query the data dictionary of the source database to get the timestamp columns?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: Good idea, that would have worked too.  I did finally get the regular expression working.

Comment: @stribizhev: That seems to work perfectly, thanks!  If you make it into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you need only the table name and the timestamp. I cut your own regexp, and modified it a little bit. Try this and let me know if this one make it freeze also or will run well.

```
^CREATE TABLE ([^(]+)\([^\-]+--\s+\[([^\]]+)(?=\] \[timestamp\])
```

https://regex101.com/r/nD0iK5/1

Comment: This doesn't work quite right.  Not every table in the file has a timestamp column, and this is picking up one table name and a different table's timestamp in the second sample file I provided (see https://regex101.com/r/yE7eP4/1)

Comment: After trying many thing, I think the best option would be something else, or reach your goals in more steps. Find "CREATE TABLE" AND lines which has [timestamp] (or "--"). You get X lines as result, many CREATE TABLE lines and few timestamp one. Then you do something like this: https://regex101.com/r/nD0iK5/2  . In a 3rd step you take out only the data you need. Or you may combine 2nd and 3rd step into one. If you need help for each steps, let me know.